# Testng not executing all tests in suite

Tags: java, testng

We have a large suite of tests that run on jenkins. In total we have about 700 tests and counting. When we execute this suite only about 450 actually run. There seems to be many classes that don't run at all. I've ran the `.xml` in "dryrun mode" to see if the problem was there, but every test got executed. This leads me to belive the problem is not in how I formated the `.xml` file or importing the wrong **`@Test`** annotation. All in all it takes about 90 mins to run. In the logs there is no mention of the classes that failed to execute. So it seems like it didn't even try.

My `.xml` file (removed some packages for privacy purposes)

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<!-- parallel="methods" -->
<suite name="Regression" parallel="methods" thread-count="15">
    <test name="Regression">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="Regression" /> 
                <exclude name="flickering" />
                <exclude name="LocalTestOnly"></exclude>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <packages>
            <package name="tests.common.*" />
            <package name="tests.data.*" />
            <package name="tests.home.*" />
            <package name="tests.insight.*" />
            <package name="tests.organizations.*" />
            <package name="tests.pdmpLinks.*" />
            <package name="tests.registration.*" />
            <package name="tests.samReport.*" />
            <package name="tests.settings.*" />
            <package name="tests.training.*" />
            <package name="tests.userProfile.*" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Dry run: 696 tests ran

Prod run: 443 (87% pass)